Why is Telegram snap disk usage so high?
This is a self answered question to help others.
Telegram disk usage is extremely high:
$ cd ~/snap/telegram-desktop
$ du * -hs
1.1G    4208
346M    4353
808M    4384
1.6G    4486
1.3G    4743
95M     5133
584M    6055
149M    6088
2.0M    common
0       current

The Telegram 4000 series of directories are using 1.1G + 343M + 808M + 1.6G + 1.3G = 5.2G of disk space.
Can some or all of Telegram's "wasted" 5.2 Gigabytes of disk space be recovered?

How many snap application versions are kept?
A snap application keep older versions on disk. The version count for applications range from 2 or 3 to perhaps dozens depending on your configuration.
To see which versions of Telegram snap are being kept
$ lsblk | grep telegram
loop6         7:6    0 446.2M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/6055
loop5         7:5    0 446.5M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/6088

To double check Telegram snap versions being kept
$ snap list --all | grep telegram
telegram-desktop     5.3.0               6088   latest/stable  telegram-desktop**  -
telegram-desktop     5.2.3               6055   latest/stable  telegram-desktop**  disabled

Reviewing the Telegram snap directories and delete those that shouldn't be kept
$ cd ~/snap/telegram-desktop
$ ll
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 11 rick rick 4096 Aug 17 12:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x  5 rick rick 4096 Dec 25  2023 ../
drwx------  5 rick rick 4096 Oct  1  2022 4208/
drwx------  4 rick rick 4096 Dec  7  2022 4353/
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 Jan  2  2023 4384/
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 Feb  7  2023 4486/
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 Apr 25  2023 4743/
drwxrwxr-x  4 rick rick 4096 Nov 16  2023 5133/
drwxr-xr-x  4 rick rick 4096 Jul 14 17:53 6055/
drwxr-xr-x  4 rick rick 4096 Aug 17 12:47 6088/
drwxr-xr-x  3 rick rick 4096 Jul 30  2022 common/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 rick rick    4 Aug 17 12:47 current -> 6088/

$ rm -rf 4208 4353 4384 4486 4743 5133
Summary
In each Telegram snap version, media files downloaded to date are in the snap sub-directory. You can clean up media files in the current Telegram version but, older versions keep what was downloaded.
Use the rm -rf command with care. See Home folder contents lost: wrong use of rm?
Saving 5.2 Gigabytes of disk space may not seem like a lot on a 1 or 2 Terabyte storage device. However the Ubuntu partition only had 700 MB available, so the 5.2 GB recovered was a huge benefit.
